# Is there anyway to get a list of all the chat members in Telegram?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Is there anyway to get a full list of the members in a Telegram group? We are selling subscriptions to a Telegram Group/Channel but we have two problems

1. No Join Event on Channels only Groups (So we cannot log people who only join the channel)
2. We can't cross check our member list on the website with the Telegram list to see who is in the group/channel that isn't paying

What is the best solution? On Discord we can do this easily, is there anyway at all to get a full list of the Telegram Users, even if it isn't their ID's, but just their names/usernames?